# can :manage, :all works but can :manage, :Micropost does not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

`can :manage, :all` works but `can :manage, :Micropost` does not work

I have a micropost model. What am I missing???

Here is the code: https://github.com/brunopgalvao/prana/tree/cancan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code, I think if you try

```
can :manage, Micropost
```

that should hopefully work.

Check out [Defining Abilities in the Cancan wiki](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities)

Hope this helps